# How to toggle on or off SwichTileList based on some condition in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I was working with switchTileList in flutter what I exactly want is to ask a user multiple permissions when toggling the switchTileList button and if all permission's granted I want to toggle on the button but if not all permission's granted i want the button to toggle off.
Below is My code but not working properly as i want

```
void _askPermission() async {
    Map<Permission, PermissionStatus> statuses = await [
      Permission.camera,
      Permission.sms,
      Permission.contacts,
      Permission.locationAlways,
      Permission.microphone,
      Permission.storage,
      Permission.photos,
    ].request();

    if (statuses[Permission.location]!.isDenied &&
        statuses[Permission.camera]!.isDenied &&
        statuses[Permission.sms]!.isDenied &&
        statuses[Permission.contacts]!.isDenied &&
        statuses[Permission.storage]!.isDenied &&
        statuses[Permission.photos]!.isDenied) {
      print("ALL permission is denied.");
    } else if (statuses[Permission.location]!.isGranted &&
        statuses[Permission.camera]!.isGranted &&
        statuses[Permission.sms]!.isGranted &&
        statuses[Permission.contacts]!.isGranted &&
        statuses[Permission.storage]!.isGranted &&
        statuses[Permission.photos]!.isGranted) {
      _isAllPermissionGranted = true;
      print("ALL permission is Granted.");
    } else {
      print("Something Happend");
    }
  }




 SwitchListTile(

             // contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(30),
              title: Text(
                'Activate All Permission',
              ),
          activeColor: Colors.lightBlue,
          activeTrackColor: Colors.blue,
          inactiveTrackColor: Colors.blueGrey,
              subtitle: Text('Activate the permissions necessary for proper functioning of the application'),

                onChanged: (bool value) {
                  _askPermission();

                  if(_isAllPermissionGranted){
                    setState(() => _darkMode = value);
                  }else if(!_isAllPermissionGranted){
                    value = false;
                    setState(() => _darkMode = value);
                  }

              }, value: _darkMode,
```

Comment: Can you include the code after your `SwitchListTile` i.e. the code where the other permissions are defined?

Comment: I have included the permission code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make your `onChanged(bool value)` async and await the execution of the `_askPermissions()` method

Like so

```
onChanged: (bool value) async {   // Make this async
         await _askPermission(); // Wait for this to complete and only 
                                //then execute the further code
             if(_isAllPermissionGranted){
                    setState(() => _darkMode = value);
             }else if(!_isAllPermissionGranted){
                    value = false;
                    setState(() => _darkMode = value);
             }

        },
```